# Mixed user Session IDs in Load Balanced Environment

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

Environment Setup:

```
 1 Load Balancer (Windows Server 2008R2 & Web Farm Framework & Application Request Routing)
 3 Web Servers (Windows Server 2008R2)
 1 SQL Server (Sessions are stored in sql session state database by IIS)
```

Our server admin created all servers in VMWare using the clone mechanism. The load balancer and web servers do have the same SIDS.

We have an issue with users getting each others sessions on a rare basis. Our outputcache in our web.config: enableKernelOutputCache="false"

Does anyone know if having the same SID on all servers creates the issue our users are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to our shopping cart provider using asp.net anonymous authentication. Guids were tied to data in the database and as our site received very heavy traffic asp.net would generate random GUIDS and sometime users would receive the same session.